# On some tiny percentage of reads across userbase, C# `File.ReadAllText` giving string consisting solely of of null characters (\u0000) on Windows

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, json.net

We're seeing a decent volume of errors in our analytics when certain users of our application try to read save files. 99.9%+ of reads across our entire user base go fine, but we get a handful of these errors in our error telemetry data.

From what we can tell, in some tiny % of reads, `File.ReadAllText` outputs a long string of null characters:

`\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 ...etc`

The number of null characters seems to match the size of the user data file, but it's hard to tell exactly for sure, and we don't have a way of reproducing the issue.

Subsequent reads / parsings of the same exact files appear to happen fine (from what I can tell from the analytics surrounding the events).

Is this a common random occurrence on `File.ReadAllText` on Windows machines? What could possibly be causing this read (possibly writing?) of all-null-character files?

Comment: What is the code that creates this file?

Comment: 1) It appears you are trying to deserialize your JSON into a type called `SettingsData`.  Can you share it?  2) Can you share the *complete* contents of a JSON file that is causing the exception?  What you show above is not a valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) file as it is missing the outer curly braces `{` and `}`.  3) Along with the traceback can you share the exception message, type, and inner exception, if any?

Comment: This is not from a local run, this is from telemetry data. 99% of the time, files load fine. The error we are seeing is that File.ReadAllText appears to result in a string full of only null characters, roughly the length of the file on the user's machine.

Because I do not have access to the user's computer, and this is only based on analytics data, I have no way of reproducing what the issue could be yet. If anyone has ideas on how to extract further useful info via telemetry or how to try to reproduce locally, I'd love to try anything.

Comment: Updated to a more minimal description of the problem (believe the JSON parsing is irrelevant to the issue, just what happens to attempt to digest the erroneous reading of a file's worth of null characters and how we got the error data in our analytics which reports crashes).

Answer (score 0):

`\u0000` is a null character, therefor there must be something wrong with your retrieval method or your file path in general. Assuming that your code is possibly faulty in some manner as you have not displayed any maybe give this a try?

```
//Open the file              
var stream = File.OpenText("json file.txt"); 
//Read the file              
string st = stream.ReadToEnd();                           
var jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(st);              
foreach (var item in jsonArray){                                   
    JsonObject ob = new JsonObject(item);                   
    foreach (var t in ob.Values){                       
        JsonObject oo = new JsonObject(t);                       
            foreach (var x in oo){                          
                textBox1.AppendText(x.Key + " : " + x.Value + "\n");                      

           }                  
    } 
}
```

Code Reference: [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/473958/howplustoplusread-fwriteplusJsonplusonplusC).

Comment: Just to clarify, this works for me locally and for 99%+ of our file reads across all of our users. This is a deployed game. The issue is that File.ReadAllBytes is giving us a string that is all null characters. I'm wondering in what scenarios Windows would ever return (or save?) that.

Those same users are able to later read those same files properly (and deserialization is never an issue when the file contents is correct, this is all due to the file being read into a string of all null characters).